# How to pass loop and dynamic task id in jinja template in Airflow BashOperator and SSHOperator

Tags: loops, templates, jinja2, airflow

I am trying to create multiple task in loop and pass the dynamically generated task ids of `PythonOperator` in the `BashOperator` and `SSHOperator` for XCOM pull.

```py
for group_key in range(1,5):
    dag = create_dag(group_key)
    globals()[dag.dag_id] = dag

    for i in range(2):  
        delete_xcom_task = PostgresOperator(
          task_id='delete-xcom-task_'+str(i),
          postgres_conn_id='pg_airflow_db',
          sql= "delete from xcom where dag_id= '" + dag.dag_id + "' ",
         dag=dag)

        t0_get_next = PythonOperator(
            task_id='load_hist_pkg_to_ts_'+ str(i),
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=load_hist_pkg_to_ts,
            xcom_push=True,
            op_kwargs={'pg_conn_id':pg_conn_id,
                       'pg_conn_schema': pg_conn_schema,
                      },
            dag=dag)

        t1_check_file=ShortCircuitOperator(
            task_id='check_if_file_exist_'+str(i),
            python_callable=_check_files,
            provide_context=True,
            op_kwargs={'load_hist_pkg_to_ts_cnt':'load_hist_pkg_to_ts_'+str(i),
                      },
            dag=dag,
        )

        t0_move_file = BashOperator(
            task_id='bash_move_file_'+str(i),
            bash_command= "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key = 't0_bash_move_file' , task_ids = 'load_hist_pkg_to_ts_~i~' , dag_id = ti.dag_id) }}",
            dag=dag)


        t1_copyfile = SSHOperator(
            ssh_conn_id='ssh_execute_rempte',
            task_id='ssh_file_to_postgres_'+str(i),
            xcom_push=True,
            command= "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key = 't1_bash_copy' , task_ids = 'load_hist_pkg_to_ts_~i~' , dag_id = ti.dag_id) }}",
            dag=dag)

        t2_archive_file = BashOperator(
            task_id='bash_archive_file_'+str(i),
            bash_command= "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key = 't2_bash_remove_file' , task_ids = 'load_hist_pkg_to_ts_~i~' , dag_id = ti.dag_id) }}",
            dag=dag)

        delete_xcom_task>>t0_get_next >>t1_check_file>>t0_move_file>>t1_copyfile>>t2_archive_file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved  --  had to do like below

```
bash_command= "{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key = 't2_bash_remove_file' , task_ids = 'load_hist_pkg_to_ts_{}' , dag_id = ti.dag_id)}}}}".format(i),
```